# Backgroundcolor for matplotlib.pyplot tables

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, background-color

Dear Stackoverflowers,

**Following the advice from Paul Brodersen in his last comment, I rewrited this post by including a reproducible code**

The problem is still the same:

I inserted a table within a matplotlib plot but **can't color the cells**. Hereafter is the plot, with the table in the bottom right corner:

[image]

The code I used for producing the output you can see above is the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('seaborn')
col_labels=['p','quantile']
row_labels=['']*4
table_vals=[[0.025,0.0415],
            [0.050,0.0462],
            [0.950,0.1333],
            [0.975,0.1464]]
the_table = plt.table(
    cellText=table_vals,
    colWidths=[0.05] * 3,
    rowLabels=row_labels,
    colLabels=col_labels,
    cellColours = ['w' * 2] * 4,
    cellLoc='right',
    rowLoc='left',
    bbox=[0.70, 0.10, 0.25, 0.25], 
    edges='horizontal'
    )
the_table.auto_set_font_size(False)
the_table.set_fontsize(16)
```

The instruction `cellColours = ['w' * 2] * 4` was intended (in my mind) to give white background color to the cells.
As you see, this doesn't work...

**My question**: is there a specific instruction to apply a given *background* color to a table constructed by `plt.table` as in the above code?

Note that I would prefer to apply a background color to the **entire** table (including cells containing headers of rows and cols), but, if it's not possible, what would be the proper way to apply a specific background color to the numerical cells?

Comment: This looks like you are using seaborn. I wonder if the seaborn tesselation has a higher zorder than the table background rectangles (but a lower zorder than the text). Can you set the table zorder explicitly to a high value or, alternatively, not use seaborn (and set a different colour than white for testing)?

Comment: @Paul, yes, it's seaborn. But what that strange name of `zorder` means?

Comment: Plot elements can overlap and then occlude each other. The z-order of the elements determines which element is plotted on top. Elements with higher z-order are plotted above elements with lower z-order. `zorder` is the name of the parameter that allows you to control the placement of each plot element in this hierarchy. All plot elements should have a `zorder` parameter, including `plt.table` elements.

Comment: I understand. I gave `zorder=1` to the plot and `zorder=2` (then `zorder=5`) to the table, but it doesn't change anything... The only way out I found to to better highlight the table is to cancel the white grid by `ax.grid(False)`, which is not what I wanted (create a background color for the table). Maybe not possible???

Comment: I am sure that your problem can be solved but it is very hard to debug such things without a [self-contained, minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I would suggest that you re-work your post such that others can run the code and reproduce the issue on their machine.